# How to read the first few lines of a tsv.gz file in python?

Tags: python, csv

How to read the first few lines of a tsv.gz file in python?
I wrote the following lines:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('HELLO.tsv.gz', 'rb') as f:
    tsv_file = f.read() 
    read_tsv = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t")

    number_of_lines = 10

    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        line = read_tsv.readline()
    
print(line)
```

However, it comes the error:

```
name 'csv' is not defined
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe you just forgot to import the csv package, place this at the top of your code: `import csv`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added `import csv` and `.decode()`,  but it shows `_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'readline.`  Why does it happen? I am an absolute beginner and spent hrs trying to open a file.....

Comment: `csv` doesn't give line with string but it reads line and convert this string to list of values - `row` - and this is why it doesn't have `readline()`. You can try `for row in read_tsv[:10]:` or `list(read_tsv)[:10]` or you can repeate 10 times `row = next(read_tsv)`. You should check doc for [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: if you want it as string then you can use directly `f.readline()` in loop.

Answer (score 2):

`csv` doesn't have `readline()` and documentation doesn't use name `line` but `row`

---

If you want `line` as `string` then you can do it direectly

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('HELLO.tsv.gz', 'rb') as f:
    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        line = f.readline()
        print(i, line)
```

If you want `line` as `list of values` (`row of data`) then you can use `next()` to get next `row` from `csv`

```
with gzip.open('hello.tsv.gz', 'rb') as f:

    data = f.read().decode()
    #print('--- data ---')
    #print(data)
    #print('---')
    
    tsv_reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter="\t")

    number_of_lines = 10

    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        row = next(tsv_reader)
        print(i, row)
```

You can also use `list(...)[:10]` to get it as list of rows

```
with gzip.open('hello.tsv.gz', 'rb') as f:

    data = f.read().decode()
    #print('--- data ---')
    #print(data)
    #print('---')
    
    tsv_reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter="\t")

    number_of_lines = 10

    rows = list(tsv_reader)[:number_of_lines]
    print(rows)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Original version has one problem - it uses `read()` to read all file to memory and it is useless to get only few starting rows.

I found `gzip` can use mode `rt` to give lines decoded to `string` and then you don't have to use `read().decode()` and you can use `f` directly in `cvs.reader()` and read only few rows without reading full file.

```
with gzip.open('hello.tsv.gz', 'rt') as f:

    tsv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")

    number_of_lines = 10

    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        row = next(tsv_reader)
        print(i, row)
```

---

Doc: [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)